# Nexus Maven m2Eclipse Issue

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, nexus

I installed the latest Nexus 1.9 on to my tomcat instance. Here are the steps I took.

1. Copied War file to Tomcat Webapps directory.
2. Started Tomcat
3. Logged into Nexus Admin Console.
4. went through and set all the proxy repositories "Download Remote Indexes Settings" from False to True and saved settings.
5. Reindexed all repositories.
6. Also made sure to be snapshot and not releases for Repository Policy.
7. went to the Public Repositories and added all the repositories to Available Repositories section and saved settings
8. Reindexed Public Repositories.

Downloaded Maven 3.0 and installed it.
I updated my settings.xml to be like the one in the following example
http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html with my url pointing to "http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.0/content/groups/public"

I then went over and installed m2Eclipse into my new Eclipse 3.6 install.

Everything up to this point was going smoothly but when I try to create a brand new Maven Project I get errors and when I try to add dependencies and search I get nothing.

The Error I'm getting is 
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Could not calculate build plan: Failure to find org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:jar:1.0 in http://localhost:8080/nexus-webapp-1.9.0/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced   com.roo.sample      Unknown Maven Problem

I also downloaded Springsource STS and trying using that instead of Eclipse 3.6 with no luck.

I also had a ton of errors about jars missing.

I worked with Nexus and Maven about 2 years ago and I remember it being pretty easy to install and get going.  I remember going over to add dependencies and being able to search for most of the public jars with no problem.  This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to force maven to check the repository by the "-U" flag. This will disregard any *.lastUpdated files in your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into Nexus and select "Update
   Index" and "Expire Cache" on the items in question.
2. Go into your local .m2 folder and
   remove the relevant *.lastUpdated
   files.